# Regex for catching port numbers

Tags: regex, port

I need a regex to catch the following situations:

- Can't have a comma ',123' on the begining;
- Can't have 2 commas '123,,123' together;
- Can't have a comma '123,' on the end;
- Can't have more than 1 hyphen '123-456-789' to range ports, it should be only '123-456';

So far I've come with this:

```
(^[0-9]+)(^(?!.*(,,)).*$|(([0-9]+\-[0-9]+,?)|([0-9]+,?))+)([0-9]$)
```

This is ok:
121,123-200,2323

This is not ok:
','121,123-200'-'300',,'2323,'-'500','

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve here. From string like ','121,123-200'-'300',,'2323,'-'500',' you want to get 121,123-200,2323, yes? Ain't easier to clean string first in some language you like?

Comment: [`^(\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/IGp7iB/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to express what you want, instead of what you don't want:
That is:

- a number or a range (`\d+(?:-\d+)?`),
- and maybe a comma followed by another number/range (`(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*`).

You can use [`^(\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/IGp7iB/1)

Since you mention OracleDB, you might want to avoid using `\d`:
[`^([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/IGp7iB/2)

Comment: I tried in Oralce DB and it does not return anything...
SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('121,123-200,2323', '^(\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*)$');

Comment: Ok, if you are using Oracle DB, you might wanna replace `\d` by `[0-9]`. Updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following regex:

```
^((?:[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?)(?:,[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?)*)$
```

You can visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/K1eVhC/4) to test it.